# Rails6 + Nginx + Passenger + ActionCable = websocket is closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, actioncable

There is a similar - unanswered - question for Rails 5, but, as I am using Rails 6 I am asking again.

I have some troubles working my action cable in production environment. **Development env is working fine.**

Error to solve : `WebSocket connection to 'wss://myapp.com/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`

I'm getting this error multiple times on Chrome's console.

Stack

- Ruby 2.6.5
- Rails 6.0.3.2
- Nginx 1.14.0

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;

  server_name *.myapp.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem;

  root /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name myapp_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }
}
```

**cable.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: redis

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: myapp_production
```

**production.rb**

```
  config.action_cable.url = 'wss://app.myapp.com/cable'
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'https://app.myapp.com' ]
```

These lines constantly repeat in the log:
**log/production.log**

```
I, [2020-09-15T13:05:02.679580 #32158]  INFO -- : Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for xxx.xxx.133.88 at 2020-09-15 13:05:02 +0000
I, [2020-09-15T13:05:03.791781 #32158]  INFO -- : [2c7c3ddf-e0d9-4f6b-80d5-ace193462c8a] Started GET "/cable" for xxx.xxx.133.88 at 2020-09-15 13:05:03 +0000
I, [2020-09-15T13:05:03.792248 #32158]  INFO -- : [2c7c3ddf-e0d9-4f6b-80d5-ace193462c8a] Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for xxx.xxx.133.88 at 2020-09-15 13:05:03 +0000
I, [2020-09-15T13:05:03.792320 #32158]  INFO -- : [2c7c3ddf-e0d9-4f6b-80d5-ace193462c8a] Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPG
```

**browser console**

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://app.myapp.com/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please comment this line in your production.rb

```
config.action_cable.url = 'wss://app.myapp.com/cable'
```

Also, make sure to have this line in your view layout file default name is application.html.erb.

Add this in the head section.

```
<%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
```

[Documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#consumer-configuration) states that:

```
8.3 Consumer Configuration

To configure the URL, add a call to action_cable_meta_tag in your HTML layout HEAD. This uses a URL or path typically set via config.action_cable.url in the environment configuration files.
```

Why this is needed in production and not development is not explained or clear.

Comment: the meta_tag method will add <meta name="action-cable-url" content="/cable"> in your layout and gives the action cable URL in your layout

Comment: Ok - but I guess I am asking what this does, because in the dev enviroment this isn't needed and also I can see the site hitting the server even without that tag. And if it is required, why isn't it mentioned somewhere in Rails code in a default generated app that has actioncable enabled!

Comment: Yes it works, but the answer requires an explanation as to WHY it works.

Comment: It is mentioned in the rails documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#consumer-configuration Hopefully that will answer your question.

Comment: Also, can you mark this question usable and correct? So it will help other users as well